# How to select an element by it's value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML-source

```
<tr>
  <td>Peter Pan</td>
  <td>Nervland</td>
  <td>
    <a href="edit/id-for-peterP">edit</a>
    <a href="delete/id-for-peterP">delete</a>
  </a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Wendy</td>
  <td>Nervland</td>
  <td>
    <a href="edit/id-for-wendy">edit</a>
    <a href="delete/id-for-wendy">delete</a>
  </a></td>
</tr>
```

The task is to

> choose the edit-link in the row that also contains a cell which contains "Peter Pan"

How can I (efficiently) solve this problem?

Comment: Is modifying the HTML possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: I'd suggest putting classes on your edit and delete links, so they're slightly easier to identify using selectors, but if you can't modify the HTML then it's a bit irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the row that contains the string `Peter Pan` and then find the link with href attribute starting with `edit` and make it red:

```js
$('tr:contains("Peter Pan") a[href^=edit]').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Peter Pan</td>
  <td>Nervland</td>
  <td>
    <a href="edit/id-for-peterP">edit</a>
    <a href="delete/id-for-peterP">delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Wendy</td>
  <td>Nervland</td>
  <td>
    <a href="edit/id-for-wendy">edit</a>
    <a href="delete/id-for-wendy">delete</a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$( "td:contains('Peter Pan')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about other text in the field use [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/),

```
var anchor = $('tr:has(td:contains("Peter Pan")) a[href^=edit]');
```

but if you want the entire text to match, use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a boolean function like this:

```
var anchor = $('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "Peter Pan";
}).closest('tr').find('a[href^=edit]');
```

it finds all TDs, then filters based on exact text matching, then finds the nearest ancestor TR and the link within that.